# Managing node packages in a optimized way

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, jasmine

I am newbie in Node.js.

Whenever I want to install a package, I do it like

```
"npm install -g package-name"
```

What I have seen inside my node applications there is a dir "node_modules" been created and all the installed modules are there.

Then I want to use "grunt" for automating my tests for frontend javascirpt unit tests.

And I ran the command for installing  `"npm install -g grunt"` but when I go inside my test directory and run grunt I get `"Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt."` But if I install it inside the "test" directory it works fine.

My project structure like below:

```
-backend
     -tests
     -model
     -node_modules
     -package.json
     -others
-frontend
     -tests
     -js
     -package.json
     -node_modules
     -others
```

How I can manage node packages from a single pacakge.json and run the tests separately in frontend and backend? What are the optimized way of doing this stuff?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `-g` flag in npm will install the module globally -- this is how things like `grunt` work as a CLI tool, but for your dependencies, you probably just want them to be installed in your `node_modules` folder, defined in your `package.json`.

Are you browserifying your front-end modules? You most likely do not want both your front and back end to have the same set of dependencies, best to keep them separate package.json manifests. Are your frontend modules just grunt tasks? Running `grunt` in either `frontend` or `backend` directories will call the gruntfile only there.

Keep these two directories separate -- will save a lot of headache in the future.

Comment: Did that help? Generally tests are run using `npm test`, with a test script specified in your package.json in node, and then some build tool for your front end, like grunt.

Comment: it didn't help, and I want to run both the tests(front and backend) from command line.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is then. You could have a bash script to easily call `cd backend && npm test && cd ../frontend && grunt test` if you just want them in the same command? What is preventing you from testing currently?